# Google Maps (Reverse) Geocoding API should display only Cityname

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps, geolocation

Im using the Google Maps GeolocationAPI to retrieve the Cityname of given Coordinates ( this is called reverse geolocation). Documentation is available [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=en#ReverseGeocoding)

i send a post request with jquery and get a JSON formatted object at my script its this array: `locationName[]`.

for some coordinates i have success displaying the city name using:

```
locationName[0].address_components[0].long_name;
```

but for some coordinates the city name is at

```
locationName[0].address_components[1].long_name;
```

or even at

```
locationName[0].address_components[3].long_name;
```

additionally i want to display the City district (if its available for the given coordinates if not then i only want to display the cityname)

how can i determine which field in the array is the city name and how to determine if a city district is available and if so in which field it is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is basically about checking objects for a particular value in an array attribute and returning that object if the value is found in the array.  Here's one way you can do it -

```
var desiredLocationDescription;
var addressComponentArray = [];
var typeName = "locality";


for (var i = 0; i < locationName[0].address_components.length; i++){
    addressComponentArray.push(locationName[0].address_components[i])
}

for (var i = 0; i < addressComponentArray.length; i++){
    if (addressComponentArray[i].types.includes(typeName)){
        desiredLocationDescription = addressComponentArray[i];
        break;
    }
}

console.log(desiredLocationDescription.long_name)
```

Since the city name is stored in the object with the `type: ["locality", "political"]`, look through the array of objects until you find the one with 'locality' in its types.

Comment: nice this only gives the city name :)

Comment: As far as getting the districts, you could use the same strategy. You'd need to know the API's type name for that, but then you can just check if it exists and if so, set the variable accordingly.

Comment: i will have a closer look at the documentation to get the name of the type of city district. thanks a lot for this quick solution!

Comment: No problem. I love map tools!

Comment: for those who are interested the name of the type of city district  is "sublocality" and therere you can also say sublocality_level_1 to sublocality_level_5. Each sublocality level is a civil entity. Larger numbers indicate a smaller geographic area.